# React Native Android: Camera Permission Pop up not opening on mobile device

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native for mobile development. My question is that camera Permission Pop up not showing up on mobile device.

I have read many answers on stack overflow which suggest to add entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I have already tried this - but still not able to see pop up permission.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.xyz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My react native code (taken from official doc):

```
const takePermissions = async() => {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(
         PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
         {
           title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
           message:
             "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
             "so you can take awesome pictures.",
             buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
             buttonNegative: "Cancel",
             buttonPositive: "OK"
         }
    );
    }

...

    useEffect(() => {
        takePermissions();
    }, []);
```

I am unable to see pop for camera permission on my mobile device.

**EDIT:**
I noticed that as soon as my app is installed on the mobile device, it already gets permission of camera and storage **automatically**. Because of this permission pop-up is not shown when user opens app. I tried deleting the camera and storage permissions in AndroidManifest.xml and tried again - but sadly faced the same behaviour - the camera and storage permission are already granted in app settings - and therefore the permission pop-up dialog is not shown. How to correct this?

Even if I uninstall and re-install - the app gets camera and storage permission **automatically** in the app settings. Because of this, sadly,  permission pop-up is not showing in the app. This is the problem. What I want is that when the user opens the app for the first time they should see permission pop-up.

How is the camera and storage permissions being automatically granted in app settings? Even if I uninstall and re-install?

Comment: What's the result from the request()? User could have denied your permission. You may expect a few possible results from request, which are `GRANTED`,`DENIED` and `NEVER_ASK_AGAIN`

Comment: @TommyLeong. its `GRANTED`. Also please see the EDIT section in the above question I have added just now.

Comment: If your app already has the camera permission, could you just navigate further to use the camera function? You shouldn't require to show this dialog again. Suggest you to remove the app and reinstall it again to check if permission dialog shows up on first time.

Comment: Even if I uninstall and re-install - the app gets camera and storage permission **automatically** in the app settings. Because of this, sadly,  permission pop-up is not showing in the app. This is the problem. What I want is that when the user opens the app for the first time they should see permission pop-up.